# Android JAVA java.io.FileNotFoundException exception but iOS works fine

Tags: java, android

My iOS version of this app sends this URL to the server:

```
http://myserver/api/lostpassword1?email=fyfhv@fhghg.com&lang=eng
```

And the iOS version gets back:

```
{"result":"FAIL"}
```

My Android version of the app sends the EXACT same URL to the same server and java reports (because a 404 was sent):
    `java.io.FileNotFoundException`

Here's my Android code

```
URL url = new URL(data);
urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
```

The server is a Microsoft platform.  How in the world could the server respond one way to a request from iOS, and differently to a request from Android?

I've cleaned this up a little in response to comments that came in.

Comment: "The server is a Microsoft platform." <-- Found the problem! J/k. What's error stack?

Comment: I don't know if it's only in the code you pasted or in the source code also, but you wrote the `new` keyword together with the `BufferedInputStream` in the initialization of the `InputStream`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that whether the URL is wrong or the server sends back a 404 HTTP code. Print your `data.replaceAll(" ", "%20")` and check whether the URL is correct, or, if correct, what the server sends back.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I would appreciate it if you flagged my answer as an accepted answer, since I actually said the same as you did.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the quick comments.  It turned out that the server was returning 404 if the file name was right, but the server didn't like the contents.  Apparently JAVA will ignore any returned data if the response code is 404.  iOS, on the other hand, will ignore the 404 if there is also data returned.  Summary:

iOS:  ignore 404 if there's data

JAVA (Android):  404 rules, ignore any data.